# Can't connect to VMWare Player from host machine

Tags: networking, vmware-player, ports

Running VMware player with Cent OS. Running a server in the virtual os and trying to connect to it from the host pc to no avail.
I have tried bridged, NAT, and host-only type network connections. I am able to ping my virtual machine when in NAT mode but cannot connect to the server (which hosts on UDP ports ~11000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the virtual machine and disabling iptables with sudo service iptables stop .  Then try to connect.  If it works, the firewall was blocking you.

Comment: Because a firewall blocks ports, and you had a firewall turned on ( iptables is a firewall ).  By default, I believe iptables is enabled on CentOS, and I guess it blocks that port (and many other high ports) given the default configuration.  Glad to assist.

Comment: To be sure iptables stays off after a reboot, do sudo chkconfig iptables off